# What are some modern C idioms/guidelines to prevent memory related bugs?

Tags: c

In the past few years, I can see a lot of C++ best practices recommended everywhere. The C++ guidelines aren't applicable to C even to a smaller degree. Particularly for people coming from a relatively high level language like C++ or Java (like myself), programming in C seems very dangerous.

I know that C is too low level a language to make any guarantees, but is there anything I must be careful of while writing C code so that I can minimize the chances of memory related bugs?

Comment: For anyone coming from a *lower* level language C is "easy and safe" which is why is was developed in the first place: to encapsulate assembler working practices. But uninitialised variables,  uninitialised memory allocations, and exceeding array bounds are dangerous. The compiler can warn against the first, but the others are your responsibility.

Comment: ... and if a function returns a value which is not of immediate concern, such as `scanf`, or one that returns a pointer, such as `fopen` you must test that value. It is very easy to write code that ignores them, and falls over at the first puff of wind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many techniques reffered to as *defensive programming*, too many to list here. For instance, you may adopt to always set pointer to `NULL`, when you free the allocated memory:

```
free(p);
p = NULL;
```

This avoids leaving `p` as a *dangling pointer.* The one obvious benefit is that if one calls `free` again on `p`, it would not do anything, so you potentially avoid the *double free* issue.

The second method is to use numerous tools that may help you track the ubiqutous mistakes such as buffer overflow, just to mention Valgrind and AddressSanitizer.